# How the chrome plug-in popup.html displays the current page content?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm doing a plug-in.

In the "popup.html", I want to display the current page.

For example, I'm visiting amazon, and `popup.html` shows amazon's pages.

Comment: What have you done so far?  I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to do chrome extensions to show amazon's web pages in popup.html. Amazon does not support <iframe>, <a> is clicked in popup. html,but is not work! So sad.

Comment: Does it work for any other websites?

Comment: Yes , other sites are valid, and amazon limits the use of <iframes>. But the <a> site is not valid.

Comment: So your question is how to get around Amazon's limitation?

Comment: Right, how to get around the amazon limit.Or, how do you use <a> for chrome extensions.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to do something like:

**Popup js**

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    document.getElementById('iframe').src = url;
})
```

A problem you might run into is that a lot of sites refuse you to put their site in an iframe. In that case there is nothing you can do.(Or at least nothing that I know of)

Comment: yes! Amazon refuse put it in an iframe. I don't know how to display amazon in google-chrome-extension....